# Magento 2 API - Category creation error

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.4, magento2-api

Trying to create a category through API. But i'm getting an error

```
{
    "message": "Could not save category: %1",
    "parameters": [
        "The \"Is Home Category\" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again."
    ]
}
```

Looking forward for your help...

Used code : ( Used very basic fields only )

```
{
    "category": {
        "parent_id": 2,
        "name": "TEST CATEGORY",
        "is_active": true,
        "position": 1,
        "level": 2
    },
    "saveOptions": true
}
```

Comment: "Is Home Category" sounds like some custom attribute. Did you add such attribute to your Magento and if yes, how did you add its value while using API?

Comment: @Michal Biarda Thanks bro it's a custom attribute i forgot that part. It's working fine now

Comment: I am glad I could help :-).